# Phantom Context menu items in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am having an issue with my context menu in Visual Studio 2010 that is driving me nuts. I think it started when I installed the Code Snippet Designer Extent ion but I am not 100% sure about that. I didn't notice it until after I uninstalled that extension with a few others.

I have tried reinstalling and then uninstalling the extension again but that didn't work either. I am left with these extensions on my machine DevExpress Tools, Dpack, PowerCommands for VS, Productivity Power Tools and the VS10x Code Marker.

I have another system that has all the same extensions installed but doesn't have the context menu problem and I never loaded the Snippet Designer on that machine, which is why I think the problem was caused by something in that particular extension.

Here is what it looks like. 
http://www.mydatafish.com/contextmenu.png I tried to post a picture but I need more points to do so and it is hard to explain without a picture so please take a look at the link.

Anybody have any ideas of how I can remove these phantom mene items? By the way I did try resetting the context mene through the the customize menu item in the Tools menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I am not sure how it got in the condition that it was but I found the program that was causing the problem. It was something called "Code Helper" and it was an add it that I used with VS 2005. It was listed as a AddIn for Visual Studio 2010 but wasn't inside the Addin directory for 2010.

To get rid of the problem I removed the program from the Programs and Features (Add/Remove).